# Expand All rows in Material Table

Tags: angular, multidimensional-array

This might look like a Repeated question . I am new to angular and I have a functionality where I need to have sub rows to be shown on a table.

I am using material table and found an perfect example which is working. How ever I need an expand All functionality when clicked should expand all rows in the table.

The code I found below opens only one row each time on click. I tried several things but of no use. Any help is appreciated.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-expandable-rows-filter-pagination-sorting?file=app%2Fcdk-detail-row.directive.ts

Comment: I am looking for an button outside the grid which will expand/collapse all the rows. on click

Answer (score 1):

Uncommenting the `this.render()`, works as expected. Find the example here. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-expandable-rows-filter-pagination-sort-7u6hee?file=app/cdk-detail-row.directive.ts

Comment: Thanks @Ashokan.  but there seems to be a issue with that ... if I have to collapse then I have to double click it for the first time.  I should have been more specific on my question but I am looking for an button outside which will expand/collapse all the rows. when clicked